# Can't see attached event function but noop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, dom-events

The problem is that although I have attached events (e.g. `handleClear`) in the class below, however, when I check the `onClick` event in the button dom, it shows an empty method `noop() {}` instead. As a result, it can't clear as expected.

The strange thing is that sometimes if I set breakpoints, the handler method would be there. I suspect the event attachment is related to the timing. But I can't identify when and where it misses to attach the event function. Could anyone provide some tips on resolving this? Or provide some insights?

```
class ClearHistory extends PureComponent {

    handleCancel = () => {
        console.log('handleCancel');
    }

    handleClear = (event) => {
        console.log('handleClear');
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Button key='cancel' type='button' onClick={this.handleCancel} >
                    Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button key='remove' type='button' onClick={this.handleClear} >
                    Clear
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created sandbox to test your component, and I renamed  to a html tag  because the component without any ui-library.

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/clearhistory-fq69b?file=/src/ClearHistory.js

[image]

It works but:

[image]

This is fine because the react itself takes care of the event binding.

[image]

https://the-guild.dev/blog/react-dom-event-handling-system

Comment: Hi @Daniil, thanks for creating the sandbox and also attaching the doc! It does help me understand why noop function is there.

Comment: However, for some reason, it still doesn't work for me in my local project, where the clean history method is not executed when I click.

I did try to check the react DOM property and see the event method has been assigned to onclick event, but it just doesn't trigger any thing.

Comment: @HaoyuChen, check your console for errors

Comment: yep, I checked, but it doesn't log anything when I click the button. Because sometimes when I set the breakpoints, it will show the log after clicking. I am wondering if there is any way I could what code it has been invoked after clicking.

Comment: if you didn't see any errors and logs I think that no code has been invoked. Сan you share github repo with project? Мaybe the problem is elsewhere.